# Keras: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (400,)

Tags: python, keras

I am having an issue when trying to train my model in Keras, and a Tensorflow Backend.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

# Load Data
df = np.loadtxt("features.txt", delimiter=',') 
print('Features shape:', df.shape)

labels = np.loadtxt("labels.txt", delimiter=',') 
print('Labels shape', labels.shape)

# Replace 10 by 0
labels = np.where(labels == 10, 0, labels) 

# Randomize the data 
data_shuffled, labels_shuffled = shuffle(df, labels, random_state=42)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
X = data_shuffled[:4000]
y = data_shuffled[4000:]

print(X.shape, y.shape)

# define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1000, batch_size=100, verbose=0)
# make class predictions with the model
predictions = model.predict_classes(X)
# summarize the first 5 cases
for i in range(5):
    print('%s => %d (expected %d)' % (X[i].tolist(), predictions[i], y[i]))

# evaluate the keras model
accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

Features shape: (5000, 400)
Labels shape (5000,)

I got the error on the line where I call model.fit().

Things I have tried to fix this error:
I tried to reshape the X and y numpy arrays using the following code:
X.reshape(400, -1)
y.reshape(400, -1)

But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is wrong: `y = data_shuffled[4000:]`

Should be: `y = labels_shuffled[:4000]`

Then you need to one-hot-encode:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
```

Comment: Now I get this error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: Ah that's because you have setup the network assuming the labels are [one-hot-encoded](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). I'll update the answer. Let me know if it fixes it.

Comment: Btw I'm assuming the labels are mutually exclusive? As in you can't be a member of more than one of the 10 classes at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes the labels are mutually exclusive. However, when I execute your code that you have updated, I get the following error: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[3. 5. 5. ... 7. 9. 1.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample. The shape of X is (4000, 400) and the shape of y is (4000,)

Comment: I've updated the answer. Just need to reshape the labels like: `y.reshape(-1,1)`

Comment: Thanks it works now. This works for train accuracy but how can one get the test accuracy score and the minimized error?

Comment: Well it looks like you are taking the first 4000 data points as a training set. You could use the rest as a test set?
`X_test = data_shuffled[4000:]`
`y_test = labels_shuffled[4000:]`
Then evaluate the model's accuracy with this data to get an estimate of the models true accuracy?

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know why my test accuracy is slightly higher than my train accuracy even though the minimized error for test is higher than the minimized error for train ? In my from scratch implementation, the train minimized error is actually higher than the test minimized error, why is that? Also, my accuracy is lower on my from scratch implementation is it because I used the sigmoid activation function instead of ReLU which is more efficient? I updated the code and you can find the dataset here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17FT76Qf40XVFWmSH5jFWjGf9KFss9xvz?usp=sharing

Comment: Sounds like your model might be slightly underfitting the data. Have a read of [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/overfitting-vs-underfitting-a-complete-example-d05dd7e19765) for a good explanation of under and overfitting and how to tell when it is happening. A simple way to deal with underfitting would be to increase the capacity of your model (more or larger layers). Training for more epochs can also sometimes help, but it looks like you are training for a long time already (1000 epochs).